# EWS Message Tracking Report

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I've been doing a bunch of research on how to get a message tracking report from exchange using EWS and can't seem to pinpoint anything. I was going to build an application that scrapes the log files but if I can do it through EWS it be better for what I'm doing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this? What info do you need in your message tracking report?

Comment: @MimiGentz yes I'm still looking for a solution to this. I need to be able to get all emails sent per user with the recipient list in order to determine if the email sent was internal or external.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to create a solution to my issue. I am using Powershell in C# to send commands to exchange and parse through the Message Tracking Log. In order to this you need to make sure the user you are using to connect to exchange has rights to MessageTrackingLog in exchange. The user I used has access to the RecordsManagement Role in exchange. Here is the code that allowed me to connect and get the message tracking log.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Security;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;


namespace ExchangeConnection
{
class ExchangeShell
{

    //Credentials
    const string userName = "username";
    const string password = "password";

    private PowerShell InitializePS()
    {

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, SecurePassword());
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("exchange server url/Powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 5;
        connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
        connectionInfo.OpenTimeout = 999999;

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        runspace.Open();
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        return powershell;

    }

    private SecureString SecurePassword()
    {
        System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return securePassword;
    }

    public void GetMessageTrackingLog(string sender)
    {
        PowerShell ps = InitializePS();

        ps.AddCommand("Get-MessageTrackingLog");
        ps.AddParameter("Start", DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24).ToString());
        ps.AddParameter("ResultSize", "Unlimited");
        ps.AddParameter("Sender", sender);
        ps.AddParameter("EventId", "SEND");
        Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine("|----Sender----|----Recipients----|----DateTime----|----Subject----|");
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            string senders = r.Properties["Sender"].Value.ToString();
            string recipients = r.Properties["Recipients"].Value.ToString();
            string timestamp = r.Properties["Timestamp"].Value.ToString();
            string subject = r.Properties["MessageSubject"].Value.ToString();
            string eventID = r.Properties["EventID"].Value.ToString();
            string messageInfo = r.Properties["MessageInfo"].Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", sender, recipients, timestamp, subject);
        }
        ps.Dispose();
        ps.Runspace.Dispose();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Office 365 Reporting web service would be a better solution than EWS, as it's got a number of mail traffic reports available that would suit your needs. There is more information here: [Office 365 Reporting web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984325(v=office.15).aspx) and all of the Exchange specific reports are listed here: [Exchange reports available in Office 365 Reporting web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984342(v=office.15).aspx). The MailTraffic* reports all report on messages coming into and out of the organization so you don't have to code that logic yourself.

Comment: Can you use this with on premise exchange servers?

Comment: No, just Exchange Online/Office 365.

Comment: That's the problem I'm running into. I have an on premise exchange 2010 server.